# Firebase authentication keeps blocking users out

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

I am currently using the firebase phone authenticator for my react native app but every time I try to signin with my phone, I get this error:

```
[Error: [auth/too-many-requests] We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.]
```

Anyone know how to disable this? I'm currently using the Blaze plan. Pay as you go. And the users only sent like 3-5 SMS messages. I'm very confused why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Go to `Firebase Console` ->  `Auth` -> `User Table`
2. Locate the testing user
3. Delete that user.
4. Redo the Test.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply disabling and enabling the user account.

1. Go to Firebase Console -> Auth -> User Table
2. Locate the user
3. Disable and enable the user

[View more options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3p0p.png)

[Disable/enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPjx9.png)